# Spectrum Server Analyst on AWS

Tags: mapinfo, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spectrum-spatial-analyst

I have installed Spectrum Server/SSA from Pitney Bowes on an AWS server and opened the ports to all traffic. The default site opens when I am logged in on the AWS VM, but not from any other computer.

I have the following in SSA:

[image]

The AWS security groups are:
[image]

I've tried using the elastic IP and the public DNS but it doesn't work. However, the default IIS install on port 80 works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you need to be exposed to the internet, it might be the easiest just to change the connector port of the Connect Tomcat to 80 in

C:\Program Files\Pitney Bowes\SpectrumSpatialAnalyst\Tomcat7\AnalystConnect\conf\server.xml

Below are some further notes (assuming Windows server). You may also contact the PB tech support team if you continue to have any issues.

**To expose port 8010 to the internet**

First make sure the Windows Firewall or iptables if on Linux has an inbound rule allowing port 8010 from domain, public and private networks.

- Log on to the Amazon EC2 management console
- In instances click on your running instance
- On the description tab file on the right a record called Security groups
- Click on the security group that have been set their
- Go to the inbound tab
- Click edit and add an inbound rule for port 8010

**Configuring the external URL for SSA**

In C:\Program Files\Pitney Bowes\SpectrumSpatialAnalyst\customerconfigurations_global_\shared.properties

Add the external facing URL to the first 4 entries where EXTERNALURL is the external facing domain name or IP Address

```
# Externally facing url of the adminconsole application
adminconsole.externalUrl=http://EXTERNALURL :8020/adminconsole

# Externally facing url of the connect application
connect.externalUrl=http://EXTERNALURL :8010/connect

#Customer connect location
tenant.connect.url=http://EXTERNALURL :8010/connect/@{tenant}/

#Customer theme location
tenant.theme.url=http://EXTERNALURL :8010/connect/@{tenant}/theme
```

**Configuring the hosts file for SSA**

If Admin Console is to be exposed externally then you need an entry in the local hosts file to point it at the public IP of the instance.

The hosts file is usually here C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and it has no extension

You would add the last entry as below, where 111.222.333.444 is the external IP address and EXTERNALURL is the external server name
All other lines would remain commented out.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97    rhino.acme.com          # source server
#      38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#      127.0.0.1       localhost
#      ::1             localhost
       111.222.333.444 EXTERNALURL
```

Comment: Brilliant... if anyone is interested in an AWS AMI that has SSA and Spectrum installed and configured with some base public data please give me a shout.

Answer (score 3):

- Configuring the hosts file for SSA

If it is a linux machine the the hosts file is usually in /etc/hosts rest remains the same.

Comment: Thanks. This one is windows but this is useful for my linux instances.